# Interpretation of LAD under model misspecification

Tags: least-squares, median, least-absolute-deviations

Suppose we have $n$ i.i.d. draws of $y_i$ and $x_i$ and consider a linear equation:

$$y_i =\beta_0 +\beta_1x_{1i}+...+\beta_kx_{ki}+u_i =x_i'\beta+u_i $$

A common assumption in [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) is $E[y|x]=x_i'\beta$.
If this assumption fails, OLS still has a somewhat meaningful interpretation as the best linear approximation to the conditional expectation function. (With "best" being in a squared loss sense).

In [LAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations) it is common to assume $Median[y_i|x_i]=x_i'\beta$.
My question is, if the LAD assumption fails, is there a meaningful interpretation to the LAD estimates?

I tried fiddling around with the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) but made minimal progress, and am skeptical there is a meaningful interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be shown that LAD (and more generally quantile regression) minimizes a weighted expectation of the squared specification error, $(X_i \beta_\tau-Q_\tau(Y_i |X_i))^2$, where $Q_\tau(Y_i |X_i)$ is the $\tau$th quantile of the conditional distribution fucntion and $\beta_\tau$ is the estimate from quantile regression.

Theorems 1 and 2 of [Angrist, Chernozhukov, and Fernandez-Val (2006)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2006.00671.x) is the citation.